# Java: set-size List issue UnsupportedOperationException thrown

Tags: java, list

I am having a problem changing a List that has a set-size in Java.

I understand that I can't add or remove from this list but why can't I use set?
When I use set the  UnsupportedOperationException is thrown as well as when I use add and remove which is expected.

set

```
public Object set(int index,
                  Object element)

    Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element (optional operation).
```

I understand its an optional operation its just that want to replace that one element of the list with another element. 
Is there any way I can do this?

EDIT:
I am using a LinkedList

Here is the stack trace of my issue.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Add to an immutable TypedListIterator
    at polyglot.util.TypedList.tryIns(TypedList.java:195)
    at polyglot.util.TypedList.set(TypedList.java:148)
    at itype.visit.ItypeChecker.enter(ItypeChecker.java:114)
    at polyglot.visit.NodeVisitor.visitEdgeNoOverride(NodeVisitor.java:245)
    at polyglot.visit.NodeVisitor.visitEdge(NodeVisitor.java:217)
    at polyglot.ast.Node_c.visitChild(Node_c.java:173)
    at polyglot.ast.Node_c.visitList(Node_c.java:233)
    at polyglot.ast.ClassBody_c.visitChildren(ClassBody_c.java:63)
    at polyglot.visit.NodeVisitor.visitEdgeNoOverride(NodeVisitor.java:251)
    at polyglot.visit.NodeVisitor.visitEdge(NodeVisitor.java:217)
    at polyglot.ast.Node_c.visitChild(Node_c.java:173)
    at polyglot.ast.ClassDecl_c.visitChildren(ClassDecl_c.java:159)
    at polyglot.visit.NodeVisitor.visitEdgeNoOverride(NodeVisitor.java:251)
    at polyglot.visit.NodeVisitor.visitEdge(NodeVisitor.java:217)
    at polyglot.ast.Node_c.visitChild(Node_c.java:173)
    at polyglot.ast.Node_c.visitList(Node_c.java:233)
    at polyglot.ast.SourceFile_c.visitChildren(SourceFile_c.java:121)
    at polyglot.visit.NodeVisitor.visitEdgeNoOverride(NodeVisitor.java:251)
    at polyglot.visit.NodeVisitor.visitEdge(NodeVisitor.java:217)
    at polyglot.ast.Node_c.visit(Node_c.java:177)
    at polyglot.frontend.VisitorPass.run(VisitorPass.java:56)
    at polyglot.frontend.Scheduler.runPass(Scheduler.java:596)
    at polyglot.frontend.Scheduler.runGoal(Scheduler.java:499)
    at polyglot.frontend.Scheduler.attemptGoal(Scheduler.java:440)
    at polyglot.frontend.Scheduler.attemptGoal(Scheduler.java:412)
    at polyglot.frontend.Scheduler.attemptGoal(Scheduler.java:412)
    at polyglot.frontend.Scheduler.attemptGoal(Scheduler.java:412)
    at polyglot.frontend.Scheduler.attemptGoal(Scheduler.java:364)
    at polyglot.frontend.Scheduler.runToCompletion(Scheduler.java:297)
    at polyglot.frontend.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:171)
    at polyglot.frontend.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:138)
    at polyglot.main.Main.start(Main.java:119)
    at polyglot.main.Main.start(Main.java:82)
    at polyglot.pth.SourceFileTest.invokePolyglot(SourceFileTest.java:162)
    at polyglot.pth.SourceFileTest.runTest(SourceFileTest.java:60)
    at polyglot.pth.AbstractTest.run(AbstractTest.java:32)
    at polyglot.pth.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:64)
    at polyglot.pth.ScriptTestSuite.runTest(ScriptTestSuite.java:55)
    at polyglot.pth.AbstractTest.run(AbstractTest.java:32)
    at polyglot.pth.Main.start(Main.java:41)
    at polyglot.pth.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: `java.util.List` is an interface. Which implementation are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you are using Collections.unmodifiableList, which is not modifiable, not just in size but in content.

Comment: LinkedList should support that operation, according to Sun.

Comment: Actually is there a way to find out what type of List it is? 
Because I initially set it to LinkedList but then I set it equal to another List (of type I'm not sure about)

Comment: @tuckster: I think you could answer all questions by posting the stacktrace of your exception (well, not all). To find out the type of list `System.out.println(yourList);` should give you the information.

Comment: If its set to "some" other list, all bets are off. Is there some documentation of TypedList somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it from your stacktrace, the `List` used is a [polyglot.util.TypedList](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/polyglot/api/polyglot/util/TypedList.html), which can be constructed immutable.

[`set`](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/polyglot/api/polyglot/util/TypedList.html#set%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) calls `tryIns`, which checks if the list is immutable ([see source](http://kickjava.com/src/polyglot/util/TypedList.java.htm)):

```
private  final void tryIns(Collection coll) {
  if (immutable)
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException JavaDoc(
                    "Add to an immutable TypedListIterator");
```

---

As you already found out `set` is an `optional operation` and this implementation of this List does not allow changes (if constructed immutable).

Comment: My problem was fixed by creating a new TypedList and inserting all the elements from the old list into the new one along with the new elements that I wanted to add to the list or change.

Answer (score 0):

List is an interface. It (like Collection) defines optional operations.
Optional operations are part of the interface (for consistency) but there is no guarantee that subtypes would actually support them (it kind of violates behavioral subtyping). In other words, not all actual implementations of lists have to support these operations, they just have to document whether they do.

What actual list type are you using? ArrayList? LinkedList? A custom type?

For the best of my knowledge ArrayList DOES support the set operation.
I am not sure about LinkedList
If you have a custom implementation, it may not support it unless you override the method.

Comment: should not be rather a comment than answer?

Answer (score 0):

`List` is not a class, it is just an interface. Are you implementing your own `List`? Or using a predefined one?

If it is some 3rd part library implementation of `List`, maybe that operation is simply not supported by that implementation (hence the exception).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for fixes

1. If your code creates the original list, then change the constructor call so that it is mutable.
2. Otherwise, if the code in `ITypeChecker.enter()` allows you to replace the list reference you can create a mutable list and use that,

e.g.

```
List immutable = ....; // your immutable list
List mutable = new LinkedList(immutable);
// pass `mutable` to the rest of your code so the new list is used
```